# ¿Cómo usar la api de mongodb con flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, curl

Llevo unos días intentando conectar la api de mongo con dart, pero siempre me sale este error:

> Header missing: please add content-type: application/json or application/ejson to specify payload data types

¿Alguien ya tuvo este problema antes?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api-key':
        'aqui mi key',
  };

  var data =
      '{"dataSource": "Cluster0", "database" : "Sunrise", "collection" : "users","document" : { "name": "Harvest", "breed": "Labrador", "age": 5 }}';

  data = jsonEncode(data);
  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-zbdfh/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne');
  var res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: data);

  print(res.body);
}
```

Comment: te funciona bien desde el postman?

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor en estos casos es utilizar Postman para probar las llamadas a la API. Desde ahí puedes extraer la petición a dart o a muchos otros lenguajes. Te adjunto un pantallazo para que puedas ver un ejemplo de uso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez tengas la url introducida, todos los parametros de tu variable "data" en el body y los header correspondientes haz click en send y veras que te devuelve el servidor.

Cuando te funcione correctamente, haz click en el botón de arriba a la derecha "</>" y escoge "dart", te generará automáticamente el código para tu petición.
Adjunto pantallazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acepta la respuesta si te ha ayudado a resolver el problema.

Un saludo!